# How to handle two dashes in ReST

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx to document a command line utility written in Python.  I want to be able to document a command line option, such as `--region` like this:

```
**--region**  <region_name>
```

in ReST and then use Sphinx to to generate my HTML and man pages for me.

This works great when generating man pages but in the generated HTML, the `--` gets turned into `-` which is incorrect.  I have found that if I change my source ReST document to look like this:

```
**---region**  <region_name>
```

The HTML generates correctly but now my man pages have `---` instead of `--`.  Also incorrect.

I've tried escaping the dashes with a backslash character (e.g. `\-\-`) but that had no effect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have found that one simple solution to this is to wrap the double-hyphens inside code markup, e.g. \`\`--region\`\` rather than \*\*--region\*\*.  There may be more elegant ways to solve it but that works for me.

Comment: Maybe you can use an option list: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists

Comment: Yeah, that seems kind of appropriate.  Thanks, still discovering new things in ReST all the time!

Comment: Since Docutils 0.16 (2020-01-16), a backslash escape like `**-\-option**`
works to prevent conversion to an en-dash. In Python docstrings, you still need the double-backslash, though, unless you use a `r"""raw string"""`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a configuration option in Sphinx that is on by default: the `html_use_smartypants` option (http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html?highlight=dash#confval-html_use_smartypants).

If you turn off the option, then you will have to use the Unicode character '–' if you want an en-dash.

Comment: This is of course a workaround. I consider this behaviour as bug though because it cannot be so hard to just first replace '--' with endash and after '---' with emdash.

Comment: And in the sense of this feature for example ``:command:`sphinx-build --version` `` yields a "typographically correct" command line: `sphinx-build —–version`...

Answer (score 3):

In Sphinx 1.6 [`html_use_smartypants` has been deprecated](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-html_use_smartypants), and it is no longer necessary to set `html_use_smartypants = False` in your `conf.py` or as an argument to `sphinx-build`. Instead you should use `smart_quotes = False`.

If you want to use the transformations formerly provided by `html_use_smartypants`, instead it is recommended to use [`smart_quotes`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/config.html#smart-quotes), e.g., `smart_quotes = True`.

Note that at the time of this writing Read the Docs pins `sphinx==1.5.3`, which does not support the `smart_quotes` option. Until then, you'll need to continue using `html_use_smartypants`.

**EDIT** It appears that Sphinx now uses [`smartquotes`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-smartquotes) instead of docutils [`smart_quotes`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/config.html#smart-quotes). h/t @bad_coder.

Comment: Notice to readers, syntax has changed to [`smartquotes = False`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-smartquotes). It was this one-liner configuration that solved the double-dash `--` problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
**-\\-region**  <region_name>
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To add two dashes, add the following:

```
.. include:: <isotech.txt>

|minus|\ |minus|\ region
```

Note the backward-slash and the space. This avoids having a space between the minus signs and the name of the parameter.

You only need to include `isotech.txt` once per page.

With this solution, you can keep the extension smartypants and write two dashes in every part of the text you need. Not just in option lists or literals.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @mzjn, the best way to address the original submitter's need is to use [Option Lists](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists).

The format is simple: a sequence of lines that start with `-`, `--`, `+` or `/`, followed by the actual option, (at least) two spaces and then the option's description:

```
-l     long listing
-r     reversed sorting
-t     sort by time
--all  do not ignore entries starting with .
```

The number of spaces between option and description may vary by line, it just needs to be at least two, which allows for a clear presentation (as above) on the source, as well as on the generated document.

Option Lists have syntax for an option argument as well (just put an additional word or several words enclosed in `<>` before the two spaces); see the linked page for details.

The other answers on this page targeted the original submitter's question, this one addresses their actual need.