# How to make "--" appear in sphinx instead of "-"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm having a small aesthetic problem with sphinx, I want "--" to appear in the document, but it keeps coming out as "-".

Example source:

```
remove_user (--id|--username|--email) <user_id> <source_account>
---------------
**To remove a User (and any devices associated with them) from a specific account, the following command can be used:**

* pcli.py remove_user (--id|--username|--email) <user_id> <source_account>
```

How it looks:

[image: screenshot of sphinx documentation]

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258831/how-to-handle-two-dashes-in-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's due to the `html_use_smartypants` option which is turned on by default (see [doc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_use_smartypants)). In your case you would want to turn it off.

In `conf.py`, find the line

`#html_use_smartypants = True`

And change it to

`html_use_smartypants = False`

EDIT:

[`html_use_smartypants`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_use_smartypants) has been deprecated and [`smartquotes`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-smartquotes) should be used instead.